# Recommendation for web-site aggregating accommodation in New York

Tags: online-resources, accommodation, new-york-city

I am traveling to the US east coast and I am just looking for accommodation in New York. I know that it is quite expensive in New York, but I am surprised that `booking.com` has only something about 400 hotels in this area. Is there any better aggregation web site where to look for accommodation on the east coast or US in general?

Comment: http://www.hotels.com, http://www.hotwire.com

Comment: Do you mean New York City, or New York State?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you count it, there's somewhere between about 550 and 600 hotels in New York City.

Doing a [`booking.com`](http://booking.com) search for "new york" for a random date next month, and selecting "New York City", shows "520 Hotels found in New York City".

A similar search on [Expedia](http://www.expedia.com/) finds 502 hotels. [`hotels.com`](http://hotels.com) finds 685 hotels - but then tells me that 152 of those are not available for the dates I've selected (a pattern which seems fairly consistent regardless of what dates are selected).

As far as price, hotel prices in New York can vary significantly, and especially on weekends you can get some good prices (I stayed at a great hotel in Manhattan on Friday for $150+tax), but at other times it can be very expensive - especially in Manhattan.

Comment: booking.com looks like to one with most hotels. As usual there is nothing better than that.